# How to restrict the scroll bar in excel to maximum row size using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have `50 rows` in my excel when I scroll down using the `down key`, empty rows are added in the bottom of excel `i.e past 50`. But if scroll using the scroll bar it reaches the max row size `i.e 50` and does not scroll below.

what do I do to lock the excel to `max row size(50)` so that it does not scroll below?

Comment: How would you achieve this using `Excel`? `Apache poi` only writes `Excel` files. But your requirement is a restriction in `Excel`'s `GUI`. As far as I know that kind of `GUI` restriction is not supported by `Excel`. The only thing you could do is hiding all rows that are empty. But that would not restrict the scrolling as you wants. Only `VBA` is able setting `Worksheet.ScrollArea` property. But this property is not saved in the file and would always must be set via `VBA` while opening the `Workbook`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
You are right in apache POI there's no such feature wherein u can adjust the GUI. I tried to createFreezePane so that the range of rows and columns in which data is present appears freezed.
but that does not help too. I will try something else

Comment: @Pri_stack, were you able to find a solution? I am looking for something similar. TIA.